# Typescript import mechanism in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm totally stuck right now. Using Nodejs.

Having the following setup:

Compile `-target ES5 --module commonjs`

`/def/mongoose.d.ts:`

```
export = M;

declare module M {

    export class Collection {
        name:string;
    }
}
```

`/model/users.ts:`

```
///<reference path='..\def/mongoose.d.ts' />

export var foo:M.Collection;
```

Error: `/model/users.ts(21,16): error TS2095: Could not find symbol 'M'.`

Made it as simple as possible. I tried a lot but did not managed to access the class in the mongoose.d.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a reference comment, you should import the module:

```
import M = require('./def/mongoose');
export var foo: M.Collection;
```

Usually, you would give the `.d.ts` file the same name (and location) as the `.js` file so the import statement would also load it at runtime.

Comment: This almost works. Problem now is, that it throws: `Error: Cannot find module '../def/mongoose'`. This is cause, there is no actual js file. I will see if it helps to create a .ts beside the d.ts to fix that.

Comment: When you are using CommonJS, you'll want the JavaScript file and the TypeScript definition file in the same location:
`/scripts/mongoose.d.ts` and `/scripts/mongoose.js`

Comment: so having it as external module will not work at all?

Comment: Fixed it by moving the `mongoose.d.ts` to my project root.